# Adding a processor to the lifecycle of a route in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to add my processor to the lifecycle of a route (or context) and be able to start and stop things when the route starts and stops. I don't really want to create a component for this. I have been researching and I found out I can implement `Service` and I can add my service to the context.

However, the only way I find to add it to the context is through the `Exchange`. Is there any other cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a [RoutePolicy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) which you can specify when setting up the route.
It has callbacks for onStart, onStop, onResume, onSuspend, onInit, onRemove, onExchangeBegin, onExchangeDone